# How can Function have instance methods?

Tags: javascript

MDN says that [Function object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) has instance and prototype properties (e.g. `name` is an instance property of `Function`). So I can do this:

```
function testA()
{
    console.log("testA");
}

console.log(testA.name);
console.log(Function.name);
```

But how? `Function` is an [object constructor function](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_constructors.asp). The only way to pass proprties to its instances is through `.this` keyword that saves them to its `prototype`, like this:

```
function Person(first, last, age, eye) {
  this.firstName = first;
  this.lastName = last;
  this.age = age;
  this.eyeColor = eye;
}
```

What are those instance methods and how can they be available to `Function` instances like `testA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The only way to pass proprties to its instances is through `.this` keyword that saves them to its prototype, like this:

No, adding properties to `this` doesn't add them to the function's prototype. It adds them to whatever `this` refers to in the call; in your example, assuming you call `Person` via `new` (or similar), it'll be the object being initialized by `Person`. It won't be `Person`'s prototype (`Function.prototype`), and it won't be `Person`'s `prototype` object.

> How can Function have instance [properties and methods]?

Functions are objects in JavaScript. Actual, real objects. Objects can have properties, and some of those properties can refer to functions — which effectively makes them instance methods.

So why does `Function` or `testA` have a `name` property? Because the specification says so. When you create a function:

```
function testA() {
    // ...
}
```

...the specification says it gets a `name` property and a few others (`length`, in many cases `prototype`, etc.). They're "own" properties of the object. (The object also inherits some properties, such as `apply` and `call`. It happens all of those are properties that refer to functions; e.g., they're prototype methods.)

It's no different to the spec saying that RegExp objects have a `lastIndex` or `flags` property, or that `Map` objects have a `size` property:

```js
const rex = /./g;
console.log(rex.lastIndex);  // 0
console.log(rex.flags);      // "g" (on an up-to-date JavaScript engine)
console.log(new Map().size); // 0
```

You can also add properties to functions, because...they're objects:

```js
function example(a, b) {
    console.log("a = " + a + ", b = " + b);
}
example.sayLength = function() {
    console.log("The length of this function is " + this.length);
};

example.sayLength(); // "The length of this function is 2"
```

Answer (score 2):

Methods are properties where the value is a function. Since `name` is a string, it isn't a method.

Functions are [have explicit rules for setting a name](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-instantiatefunctionobject):

> FunctionDeclaration : function **BindingIdentifier** (FormalParameters)
>   {FunctionBody}
>
> 1. If the function code for FunctionDeclaration is strict mode code, let strict be true. Otherwise let strict be false.
> 2. **Let name be StringValue of BindingIdentifier**.
> 3. Let F be FunctionCreate(Normal, FormalParameters, FunctionBody, scope, strict).
> 4. Perform MakeConstructor(F).
> 5. **Perform SetFunctionName(F, name).**
> 6. Set F.[[SourceText]] to the source text matched by FunctionDeclaration. Return F.

---

> The only way to pass proprties to its instances is through .this keyword that saves them to its prototype

No. `this` refers to the object being created by the constructor function, not to its prototype.

Comment: So those instance properties are created by JS Engine? Ok, but how they are accessed by other function objects that should only be able to access its prototype properties?

Comment: Why should other functions only be able to access properties on the prototype? If you have an object, you can access its properties.

Comment: Yeah, but  why this statement works: `console.log(testA.name);` if in this case it should only look for this property in the protoypes chain? Where in this statemenet do you see `Function,name` or something like that?

Comment: "if in this case it should only look for this property in the protoypes chain?" — Why do you think it should it only look in the prototype chain?

Comment: I wouldn't say functions are special cased. The spec just defines how the `name` property is populated, like it defines other built-in properties.

Comment: "Where in this statemenet do you see Function,name or something like that?" — What does the Function constructor function have to do with it? You aren't even using the constructor function to create `funcA`, you're using a function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are objects just like any other object. Objects can have properties. Therefore, functions can have properties. It really is that simple.

Comment: Ok, but how can this statement: `console.log(testA.name);` work if in this case it should only look for this property in the protoypes chain? Where in this statemenet do you see `Function,name` or something like that?

Comment: Why would it have to look at the prototype chain? It will only look at the prototype chain if `testA` does not have a `name` property, but it does.